# System can't find disks on boot

Tags: 10.04, server, boot

I installed ubuntu server 10.04 on a PC with two HD drives 500 GB each. I used raid1 to provide data protection. The `/boot` partition is installed also on a mirrored device `/dev/md0`.

After the installation has completed, the system did not boot properly. I got the following error message:

```
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/<long characters> does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Any idea what could cause such a problem?

**UPDATE**:

I booted into rescue mode using the installation CD. Executing fdisk showed me the partitions, but it said **"Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary."**. Can this be related to the problem at hand?

**UPDATE2:**

I re-installed ubuntu server without the Raid at all. The system booted as it should be! Also, I got the same error from fdisk after booting. So, this error should not be related to this problem of not being able to boot.

It is puzzling me. Can't I install ubuntu server 10.04 with raid1?!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably either the initramfs didn't include a raid hook.Assuming it happens after the grub menu.But why don't you use btrfs built-in raid1?

Comment: I think Grub doesnt support btrfs now

Comment: I updated my question!